# Prevent data from the same id to appear

Tags: php

I want to prevent amaun_caj , amaun_pelbagai , amaun_penalti , amaun_tunggakan from being repeated so if the id_akaun is the same the data will not appear, my code only works on amaun_caj, and for the rest, not a single data appear, what's the problem?

```
<?php 

$i = 0; $id_akaun_old ="";
while($output = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
$id_akaun           =   $output["id_akaun"];
$lokasi             =   $output["lokasi"];
$amaun_caj          =   $output["amaun_caj"];
$amaun_tunggakan    =   $output["amaun_tunggakan"];
$amaun_penalti      =   $output["amaun_penalti"];
$amaun_pelbagai     =   $output["amaun_pelbagai"];
$jumlah_bayaran     =   $output["jumlah_bayaran"];



?>



<tr>

<td>
<?php echo $i; ?>
</td>

<td>
<?php echo $jenis; ?>
</td>

<td>
<?php echo $id_akaun;
 ?>
</td>

<td>
<?php echo $no_telefon; ?>
</td>

<td>
<?php echo $lokasi; ?>
</td>

<td align="center">
<?php 
if($id_akaun != $id_akaun_old):
    echo $amaun_caj; 
    $id_akaun_old = $id_akaun;
else: echo ''; 
endif;?>
</td>

<td align="center">
<?php 
if($id_akaun != $id_akaun_old):
    echo $amaun_pelbagai; 
    $id_akaun_old = $id_akaun;
else: echo ''; 
endif;?>
</td>

<td align="center">
<?php 
if($id_akaun != $id_akaun_old):
    echo $amaun_penalti; 
    $id_akaun_old = $id_akaun;
else: echo ''; 
endif;?>
</td>

<td align="center">
<?php 
if($id_akaun != $id_akaun_old):
    echo $amaun_tunggakan; 
    $id_akaun_old = $id_akaun;
else: echo ''; 
endif;?>
</td>


<td align="center">
<?php 
if($id_akaun != $id_akaun_old):
    echo $jumlah_bayaran; 
    $id_akaun_old = $id_akaun;
else: echo ''; 
endif;?>
</td>



<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: why is your `id_akaun` not unique? this should be unique in the first place. its your primary key

Comment: id_akaun is actually not my primary key, is a foreign key from other table and it's already unique the PK for this table is id_bill, but weren't needed in the table @Ghost

Comment: then just do in the SELECT DISTINCT statement to fetch unique rows no need to process that in PHP

Comment: nothing change , would be lot helpful if u just comment on what's wrong with my code above, i'm not wanting the easy way, but it would be lot more helpful though  @Ghost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use a select distinct clause in this case, but just put them inside a container then check inside the loop:

```
<?php 
$temp = array();
$i = 1;
while($output = mysql_fetch_array($result)): 
    $id_akaun           =   $output["id_akaun"];
    $lokasi             =   $output["lokasi"];
    $amaun_caj          =   $output["amaun_caj"];
    $amaun_tunggakan    =   $output["amaun_tunggakan"];
    $amaun_penalti      =   $output["amaun_penalti"];
    $amaun_pelbagai     =   $output["amaun_pelbagai"];
    $jumlah_bayaran     =   $output["jumlah_bayaran"];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $jenis; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $id_akaun; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $no_telefon; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lokasi; ?></td>
    <?php if(!in_array($id_akaun, $temp)): ?>
        <td><?php echo $amaun_penalti; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $amaun_tunggakan; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jumlah_bayaran; ?></td>
        <?php $temp[] = $id_akaun; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php endhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using temporary variable $old_id_akaun might not be the best practice. If you still want to do it like that, i suggest you user ORDER BY id_akaun in your SQL syntax.

In my oppinion, you might get rid of temporary variable and follow these steps,

```
 1. Create empty array outside your while loop. For the sake of easy 
 understanding, let's called it $list_id_akaun.
 2. Inside your while loop, after you get $id_akaun, check whether $id_akaun 
 is inside $list_id_akaun
 3. If not exists, insert it to $list_id_akaun and continue echoing your 
 table row
 4. If exists, skip to the next row.
```